# Alarm Service Access During Custom Screen UnLock : Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, unlock, screen-lock

I am developing custom screen unlock application. In that i want to manage my default alarm service in such way that i can dismiss and snooze alarm without unlocking the screen.

But i am not getting the way to access my system alarm service..

I am handling the **TELEPHONY_SERVICE** to manage call. same way i want to handle **ALARM**.

Pleaze suggest me some idea how can i implement this fnctionality??

Thanx for your help and support in advance..

Comment: I am not getting how to handle alarm when it rings/fires?? Is there any listener available so that i can handle it without unlocking my screen??

Comment: handle which alarm? from stock alarm application? from your own application?

Comment: want to handle system default alarm application..

Comment: Then look in system default alarm application sources: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/tree/master/src/com/android/alarmclock

Comment: Ohk. If i have any query then i will ask you. Thanks..